# Referring to a value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, zen-cart

I have the following MySQL install SQL file. What I'm trying to do is modify so that is no longer refers to the installation ID as 31 but to a value set as the script is trying to run. Can anyone help?

```
# Install Easy Populate Configuration for zen cart v1.5
INSERT INTO admin_pages VALUES ('easyPopulate', 'BOX_TOOLS_EASY_POPULATE', 'FILENAME_EASYPOPULATE', '', 'tools', 'Y', '14');
INSERT INTO admin_pages_to_profiles VALUES ('1', 'easyPopulate');
INSERT INTO admin_pages VALUES ('easyPopulateConfig', 'BOX_CONFIGURATION_EASY_POPULATE', 'FILENAME_CONFIGURATION', 'gID=31', 'configuration', 'Y', '26');
INSERT INTO configuration_group VALUES ('', 'Easy Populate', 'Config options for Easy Populate', '31', '1');
INSERT INTO configuration VALUES
('', 'Uploads Directory', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_TEMP_DIR', 'tempEP/', 'Name of directory for your uploads (default: tempEP/).', '31', '0', NULL, now(), NULL, NULL),
('', 'Upload File Date Format', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_FILE_DATE_FORMAT', 'm-d-y', 'Choose order of date values that corresponds to your uploads file, usually generated by MS Excel. Raw dates in your uploads file (Eg 2005-09-26 09:00:00) are not affected, and will upload as they are.', '31', '1', NULL, now(), NULL, 'zen_cfg_select_option(array("m-d-y", "d-m-y", "y-m-d"),'),
('', 'Default Raw Time', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_DEFAULT_RAW_TIME', '09:00:00', 'If no time value stipulated in upload file, use this value. Useful for ensuring specials begin after a specific time of the day (default: 09:00:00)', '31', '2', NULL, now(), NULL, NULL),
('', 'Split File On # Records', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_SPLIT_MAX', '300', 'Default number of records for split-file uploads. Used to avoid timeouts on large uploads (default: 300).', '31', '3', NULL, now(), NULL, NULL),
('', 'Maximum Category Depth', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_MAX_CATEGORY_LEVELS', '7', 'Maximum depth of categories required for your store. Is the number of category columns in downloaded file (default: 7).', '31', '4', NULL, now(), NULL, NULL),
('', 'Upload/Download Prices Include Tax', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_PRICE_INC_TAX', 'false', 'Choose to include or exclude tax, depending on how you manage prices outside of Zen Cart.', '31', '5', NULL, now(), NULL, 'zen_cfg_select_option(array("true", "false"),'),
('', 'Make Zero Qty Products Inactive', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_ZERO_QTY_INACTIVE', 'false', 'When uploading, make the status Inactive for products with zero qty (default: false).', '31', '6', NULL, now(), NULL, 'zen_cfg_select_option(array("true", "false"),'),
('', 'Smart Tags Replacement of Newlines', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_SMART_TAGS', 'true', 'Allows your description fields in your uploads file to have carriage returns and/or new-lines converted to HTML line-breaks on uploading, thus preserving some rudimentary formatting (default: true).', '31', '7', NULL, now(), NULL, 'zen_cfg_select_option(array("true", "false"),'),
('', 'Advanced Smart Tags', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_ADV_SMART_TAGS', 'false', 'Allow the use of complex regular expressions to format descriptions, making headings bold, add bullets, etc. Configuration is in ADMIN/easypopulate.php (default: false).', '31', '8', NULL, now(), NULL, 'zen_cfg_select_option(array("true", "false"),'),
('', 'Debug Logging', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_DEBUG_LOGGING', 'true', 'Allow Easy Populate to generate an error log on errors only (default: true)', '31', '9', NULL, now(), NULL, 'zen_cfg_select_option(array("true", "false"),'),
('', 'Custom Products Fields', 'EASYPOPULATE_CONFIG_CUSTOM_FIELDS', '', 'Enter a comma seperated list of fields to be automatically added to import/export file(ie: products_length, products_width). Please make sure field exists in PRODUCTS table.', '31' , '10', NULL, now(), NULL, NULL);
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
(Sorry I forgot this...)

Isn't there a way to do this so that I don't have to use the ID 31? The 31 is supposed to represent an ID that is automatically generated from the `INSERT INTO configuration_group VALUES ('', 'Easy Populate', 'Config options for Easy Populate', '31', '1');.` command?

Comment: I know this involves using the 'SET' keyword but am not sure of how to use it in this instance.

Comment: What do you want to happen here? Substitute a new value into your query?

Comment: The gID=31 is being inserted into a column that is normally an autoincrementer. I want to change this so that instead of it being 31, it is instead the value returned from the auto insert and used throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented - use SET:

```
SET @installId = '31';
```

Then use `@installId` instead of '31':

```
INSERT INTO configuration_group VALUES ('', 'Easy Populate', 'Config options for Easy Populate', @installId, '1');
```

**UPDATE**

If the id is the last auto-incremented field from the previous INSERT statement, then you can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to retrieve it:

```
INSERT INTO configuration_group VALUES ('', 'Easy Populate', 'Config options for Easy Populate', NULL, '1');
SET @autoId = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You can then use the `@autoId` variable in place of '31' as above.

Comment: Updated Question with additional info.